# Find dangling lines

Tags: fme-form

If I have a network of roads. Each road consist of segments. I need to delete all segments that are starting segments of each road and also delete all side roads (dangling) which are represented with only one segment. I do not have idea how to realize this. Any tips? To delete such lines actually means not to proceed them further.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: FME 2011, 2012 !

Comment: I will try with the MRF2DCleaner transformer and see what I get.

Comment: MRF2DDangleRemover
Not available with current license, what kind of licence do I have to have?

Comment: MRF transformers are an extra cost item. Contact sales@safe.com for pricing info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find lines that are only a single segment by using the CoordinateCounter. Throw away anything that has a count of 2. Doesn't always mean they are a dangle though.

The surer - but longer - method would be to use the TopologyBuilder and check to see where a segment has a node ID that is not referenced by any other segment. Then it must be a dangle.

Comment: But how to detect in FME if there are duplicate from_node or that there is from_node =! to_node. I tried with Tester but it is not working as I thought.

Comment: Nope. This is really hard to solve...

Comment: Actually It would be good If I could test if _from_node of first segment is _end_node (_to_node) of second (following) segment.. If it is so, so this is not dangling line, but else it is. Am I right???? I tried to test this also with ListHistogram that is counting how many same values of an attribute exists, but with this tranformer I can check only one attribute, not two what will be solution.